# Postgres use multiple column values as jsonb object keys

Tags: postgresql

I have some data like this:

```
(VALUES 
('good', 'A', ARRAY [1,2,3]),
('good', 'B', ARRAY [5]),
('bad',  'C', ARRAY [8,9])) t (type, name, numbers)
```

The data comes from a `... GROUP BY type, name`, so I am sure that there are no duplictes there.

I would like to build a json object for each type that has the names as key and the numbers as value.
For example, for the type 'good' I'd like to have:

```
{
   "A": [1,2,3],
   "B": [5]
}
```

This is the closest I have come

```
WITH data (type, name, numbers) AS (VALUES ('good', 'A', ARRAY [1,2,3]),
                                          ('good', 'B', ARRAY [5]),
                                          ('bad', 'C', ARRAY [8,9]))
SELECT type,
       JSONB_AGG(
               JSONB_BUILD_OBJECT(name, numbers)
       ) AS things
FROM data
GROUP BY type;
```

It returns things like `[{"A": [1, 2, 3]}, {"B": [5]}]` which is not what I need.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here [Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-aggregate.html) use `jsonb_object_agg`.

```
WITH data (type, name, numbers) AS (VALUES ('good', 'A', ARRAY [1,2,3]),
                                          ('good', 'B', ARRAY [5]),
                                          ('bad', 'C', ARRAY [8,9]))
SELECT type,
       jsonb_object_agg(
               name, numbers
       ) AS things
FROM data
GROUP BY type;
 type |           things           
------+----------------------------
 bad  | {"C": [8, 9]}
 good | {"A": [1, 2, 3], "B": [5]}
```